# How to showing additional message when function finished?

Tags: javascript, firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions

Cloud Functions code

```
export const showFinishStatusWhenFinished = firestore.document("messages/{messageId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    if(snapshot.exists){
       return {message: "successful"};
    }
    return {message: "message not exists"};
  });
```

I am expect the `{message: "successful"} or {message: "message not exists"}` shows on console when function finished, But the console only returns message below when finished.

```
{
  "textPayload": "Function execution took 219 ms, finished with status: 'ok'",
  "insertId": "1ck7cklf7prjs3",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "showFinishStatusWhenFinished",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "test-project"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-03-04T06:22:01.650128942Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "labels": {
    "runtime_version": "nodejs18_20240218_18_19_0_RC00",
    "execution_id": "d20aceojsw79"
  },
  "logName": "projects/test-project/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/test-project/traces/204518f53015985820652e1124f1291e6",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-03-04T06:22:01.768221127Z"
}
```

I know i can add `console.log({message: "message not exists"});` to the function, But i will also need to return another object for testing, It will look a bit odd to me.

```
test("Log test", async () => {
  const wrapped = wrap(functions.showFinishStatusWhenFinished);
  const snapshot = firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot({}, "messages/messageId");
  await expect(wrapped(snapshot)).resolves
      .toEqual({message: "message not exists"});
});
```

And the function will look like

```
export const showFinishStatusWhenFinished = firestore.document("messages/{messageId}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    if(snapshot.exists){
       console.log({message: "successful"});
       return {message: "successful"};
    }
    console.log({message: "message not exists"});
    return {message: "message not exists"};
  });
```